SharePoint Conditional Formatting: A Date Over 1 Year Old
Helo. I'm using a SharePoint List to track annual training requirements. I would like for the column to turn a color when the individual is coming up on the 1-year mark, and when they exceed that mark. So, it would be:
365-60 = yellow
365+1 or more = red
Is this possible in SharePoint lists?

What is the type of the column: date? text? number?

It's a date column.

Go to All items -> Format current view -> Advanced mode -> Use following codes.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Date] < (@now - 5184000000), 'sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50', if([$Date] > @now,'sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground40', ''))"
}

Result:


using column formatting with JSON it's possible

{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "div",
"txtContent": "@currentField",
"style": {
   "background-color": 
   {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
         {
            "operator": ">=",/*if the date is greater than tomorrow  24x60x60x1000 = 86400000 = 1day    */
            "operands": [
               "@currentField",
               {
                  "operator": "+",
                  "operands": [
                     "@now",
                     86400000
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "red",
         {
            "operator": "?",
            "operands": [
               {
                  "operator": "<=",/*if the date is less than today - 60 days*/
                  "operands": [
                     "@currentField",
                     {
                        "operator": "-",
                        "operands": [
                           "@now",
                           5184000000 /* 86400000 x 60 */
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "yellow",
               "transparent"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}

}


Thank you for the answer.
